# Failed to link a shared library

Tags: zig

I have created a zig lib using the below code:

```
//lib/src/main.zib

const std = @import("std");

const file_paths = [_][]const u8{
    "www/x/in.txt",
    "www/emd.txt",
    "www/index.html",
    "www/e2.txt",
};

const EmbeddedFile = extern struct {
    path: [*:0]const u8,
    content: [*:0]const u8,
};

export const embedded_files = blk: {
    var fs: [file_paths.len]EmbeddedFile = undefined;
    for (file_paths) |file_path, i| {
        const embedded_file = EmbeddedFile{
            .path = file_path[0.. :0],
            .content = @embedFile(file_path)[0.. :0],
        };
        fs[i] = embedded_file;
    }
    break :blk fs;
};
```

Cross compiled it as static library from Linux to Windows as below:

```
//lib/build.zig
const std = @import("std");

pub fn build(b: *std.build.Builder) void {
    const mode = b.standardReleaseOptions();

    const target = std.zig.CrossTarget{ .os_tag = .windows, .cpu_arch = .x86_64 };

    const lib = b.addStaticLibrary("Zig", "src/main.zig");

    lib.setOutputDir("static/");
    lib.setTarget(target);
    lib.setBuildMode(mode);

    lib.install();

    const main_tests = b.addTest("src/main.zig");
    main_tests.setBuildMode(mode);

    const test_step = b.step("test", "Run library tests");
    test_step.dependOn(&main_tests.step);
}
```

Then I wrote the below file to be used as executable:

```
//exe/src/main.zig
const std = @import("std");

const EmbeddedFile = struct {
    path: [*:0]const u8,
    content: [*:0]const u8,
};

extern const embedded_files: [4]EmbeddedFile;

pub fn main() !void {
    for (embedded_files) |file| {
        std.debug.print("file:\t\t{s}\n", .{file.path});
        std.debug.print("content:\t{s}\n", .{file.content});
    }
}
```

And crossed compiled it also from Linux to Windows as:

```
//exe/build.zig
const std = @import("std");

pub fn build(b: *std.build.Builder) void {
    const mode = b.standardReleaseOptions();

    const target = std.zig.CrossTarget{ .os_tag = .windows, .cpu_arch = .x86_64 };



    const exe = b.addExecutable("Zig", "src/main.zig");
    exe.addObjectFile("../lib/static/Zig.lib");
    exe.setOutputDir("shared/");
    exe.setTarget(target);
    exe.setBuildMode(mode);
    exe.install();
}
```

And every thing done smoothly with this approach.

Now I'm trying to use the same files but by building shared lib instead of static one, so I just changed the `build.zig` files to be:

1. For the shared lib:

```
//lib/build.zig
const std = @import("std");

pub fn build(b: *std.build.Builder) void {
    const mode = b.standardReleaseOptions();

    const target = std.zig.CrossTarget{ .os_tag = .windows, .cpu_arch = .x86_64 };

    const lib = b.addSharedLibrary("Zig", "src/main.zig", .unversioned);

    lib.setOutputDir("shared/");
    lib.setTarget(target);
    lib.setBuildMode(mode);

    lib.install();

    const main_tests = b.addTest("src/main.zig");
    main_tests.setBuildMode(mode);

    const test_step = b.step("test", "Run library tests");
    test_step.dependOn(&main_tests.step);
}
```

2. For the executable file:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn build(b: *std.build.Builder) void {
    const mode = b.standardReleaseOptions();

    const target = std.zig.CrossTarget{ .os_tag = .windows, .cpu_arch = .x86_64 };



    const exe = b.addExecutable("Zig", "src/main.zig");
    exe.addObjectFile("../lib/shared/Zig.lib");
    exe.setOutputDir("shared/");
    exe.setTarget(target);
    exe.setBuildMode(mode);
    exe.install();
}
```

The shared library had been built, and I can see the files `Zig.dll, Zig.lib, Zig.pdb, Zig.dll.obj`, but with building the executable file I got the error below:

```
❯ zig build
error: lld-link: undefined symbol: embedded_files
    note: referenced by /home/hasany/Documents/Zig/embed-exe/zig-cache/o/2efedc7a8930ae173549e998c2b6a39a/Zig.exe.obj:(.refptr.embedded_files)
error: Zig...
error: The following command exited with error code 1:
/usr/bin/zig build-exe /home/hasany/Documents/Zig/embed-exe/src/main.zig /home/hasany/Documents/Zig/embed-lib/shared/Zig.lib --cache-dir /home/hasany/Documents/Zig/embed-exe/zig-cache --global-cache-dir /home/hasany/.cache/zig --name Zig -target x86_64-windows -mcpu x86_64 --enable-cache 
error: the following build command failed with exit code 1:
/home/hasany/Documents/Zig/embed-exe/zig-cache/o/6344cfbe514e2a1e155387d0d1fd1294/build /usr/bin/zig /home/hasany/Documents/Zig/embed-exe /home/hasany/Documents/Zig/embed-exe/zig-cache /home/hasany/.cache/zig
```

Comment: not sure but i think you should build `Zig.dll`. `exe.addObjectFile("../lib/shared/Zig.dll");`